# GameScreen shows Black Screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently programming a game where you have to avoid asteroids. I had to deal with some messed up coordinates and I had to guess the coordinates for sprites. I now have arbitrary units that describe my world. Unfortunately, my game screen does not work fully. When I want to render my asteroids the game screen shows a black screen.

```
public class GameScreen extends Screen {

private OrthographicCamera cam;
private Spaceship spaceship;
private Asteroids asteroids;
private Background bg;



@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    bg = new Background();
    spaceship = new Spaceship();
    asteroids = new Asteroids();

    float aspectratio = 16/10;

    cam = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * aspectratio);

    cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2f, cam.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);

    cam.update();

    }



@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    bg.render(batch);
    spaceship.render(batch);
    batch.end();

}
```

The shown code above works just fine and shows me this:

[image]

When I add the render method for the asteroids in the GameScreen class the GameScreen is just black:

```
    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    bg.render(batch);
    spaceship.render(batch);
    batch.end();

    }
```

[image]

Asteroid Class:

```
public class Asteroid {

private Vector2 p;
private Vector2 v;

private float mass;
private float radius;

public final float maxV = 200;
public final float minV = 50;

public final float rMin = 10;
public final float rMax = 30;

public final float minX = MyGdxGame.WIDTH;
public final float minY = MyGdxGame.HEIGHT;;

float alpha = MathUtils.random(0, 360);

public Asteroid(float maxX, float maxY, List<Asteroid> asteroids) {

    do {

    radius = MathUtils.random(rMin, rMax);
    masse = radius * radius * radius;

    float alpha = MathUtils.random(0, 360);

    p = new Vector2(MathUtils.random(minX, maxX), MathUtils.random(minY,
            maxY));

    float vBetrag = MathUtils.random(minV, maxV);

    v = new Vector2(vBetrag * MathUtils.cosDeg(alpha),
            vBetrag * MathUtils.cosDeg(alpha));
    } while (ueberlappMit(asteroids));

}

private boolean ueberlappMit(List<Asteroid> asteroids) {

    for(Asteroid a: asteroids){
        if(abstand(a) < radius + a.radius + 10){ //!
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}

public void update(float deltaT, float xMin, float xMax, float yMin, float yMax) {
    p.x += v.x * deltaT;
    p.y += v.y * deltaT;

    while(p.x > xMax)
    {
        p.x -=  (xMax - xMin);  
    }
    while(p.x < xMin)
    {
        p.x += (xMax - xMin);
    }
    while(p.y > yMax)
    {
        p.y -= (yMax - yMin); 
    }
    while(p.y < yMin)
    {
        p.y += (yMax - yMin); 
    } 
}


public float abstand(Asteroid a2) {

    return p.dst(a2.p);

}
```

Asteroids Class:

```
public class Asteroids extends Entity {

private final int numberofAsteroids = 150;
private float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
private List<Asteroid> asteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();

private final int cyclicBoundaryConditionsMultiple = 2; 

public Asteroids() {


    xMin = MyGdxGame.WIDTH * (-cyclicBoundaryConditionsMultiple);
    xMax = MyGdxGame.WIDTH * (cyclicBoundaryConditionsMultiple);
    yMin = MyGdxGame.HEIGHT * (-cyclicBoundaryConditionsMultiple);
    yMax = MyGdxGame.HEIGHT * (cyclicBoundaryConditionsMultiple); 


    for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {
        Asteroid a = new Asteroid( xMax,  yMax, asteroids);
        asteroids.add(a);
    }

}

@Override
public void update() {

    for (Asteroid a : asteroids) {
        a.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofAsteroids; i++) {

        Asteroid a1 = asteroids.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < anzahl; j++) {

            Asteroid a2 = asteroids.get(j);

            float abstand = a1.abstand(a2);

            if (abstand < a1.getRadius() + a2.getRadius()) {

                calculateCollision(a1, a2);

            }

        }

    }

}


}

@Override
public void render(ShapeRenderer renderer) {

    for (Asteroid a : asteroids) {

        System.out.println("RENDER A");

        renderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        renderer.circle(a.getP().x, a.getP().y, a.getRadius());

    }

    }
```

Comment: My logcat says: 

09-07 16:58:53.269: I/Timeline(24341): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42cf089 time:5449248
09-07 16:58:59.776: I/AndroidInput(24341): sensor listener tear down

Comment: Please show us your .render code?

Comment: @JonathanBotha The render Method is in the Asteriods Clss at the bottom. bg renders just the Background and works just fine without Asteroids.

Comment: If you change the color in Asteroids.render to another color. What happens then?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see you calling the `render()` method for the asteroids. Did you paste the wrong code by any chance?

Comment: I see, I meant ShapeRenderer please. Specifically .circle I have a feeling you cleared the color in that method or another which would explain the cleared (black) screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx alot for your help Guys, i solved the problem. The method private boolean ueberlappMit(List asteroids) checks if the asteroids overlap and if its the case the Asteroids shoud be created again. The Problem was that by selecting a too high radius the Game got stuck in the do while loop in the Asteroid class.