# How to set Abitrary Units properly?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently working on a **game** where you have to avoid asteroids. I started to use arbitrary units.

```
public final static int WIDTH = 100, HEIGHT = 100;
```

Additionally, I'm using an `OrthographicCamera`:

```
float aspectratio = 16/10;
cam = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * aspectratio);
cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2f, cam.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);
cam.update();
```

In the **game screen**, the **asteroids** look deformed:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the yellow blobs are the asteroid. How are they "deformed"? What's the form they should have? From your code pieces it seems like you think the problem is with the camera. Why do you think that? Otherwise maybe show us code that affects the asteroids. What happens when you resize your window?

Comment: @valid the yellow Asteroids shoud be circles. I dont know what aspect ratio fits best either? Im quite sure that the problem has nothing to to with the asteroids, because in a earlier Version without the OrthographicCamera ans aspect ratio the game looked just fine with circles as Asteroids and are sharper Spaeship. Even tough [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378730/gamescreen-shows-black-screen-solved) is the full Asteroids Code.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem of your Viewport. Have a look at [this page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#fitviewport). For example, you can use a `FitViewport` that scales your game as much as possible to fit the screen, but there may be black bars.

Answer (score 0):

Your aspect is off.  Notice your planets aren't round either. Your viewport is 500x400, which is a 5:4 aspect, you want 16:10 aspect.

Try changing

`cam = new OrthographicCamera(500, 250 * aspectratio);`

to

`cam = new OrthographicCamera(500 * aspectratio, 500);`

that will give you a viewport of 800x500, or 16:10 aspect

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong OrthographicCamera Code. Thats my OrthographicCamrea in the Game Screen:  `cam = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * aspectratio) `

Comment: then put `* aspectratio` on the left, not the right. Aspectratio is greater than 1, and you want your width greater than your height.